# Azure Data Factory/SQL and Deputy Payroll API Connection - Anonymous connection possible?

Tags: azure-data-factory

First question - is it possible to access Deputy Payroll API with only the permanent/anonymous token? If not, probably don't need to read the rest.

I have been tasked with moving data from a Deputy Payroll API to an Azure SQL DW.

I am trying to accomplish this without OAuth2.0 or Azure/Deputy Integration

According to [Deputy's documentation](https://www.deputy.com/api-doc/API/Getting_Started/) you can connect via Permanent Token.

I have used permanent tokens before and REST but I am getting different behaviour.

When I ping the Subdomain for the base deputy URL (https://business.na.deputy.com/) it returns an object with 2 points that look like the following;

```
   "Noshido__LK":"Ad8f......yd78y="

      (128/256 key?)
```

When I ping the payroll api (https://business.na.deputy.com/api/v1/resource/TimesheetPayReturn) using the token it, Data Factory tells me that I 'need to use Login, OAuth2.0, or Bearer'.

I am not familiar with these type of connections, and am hoping to work within the parameters.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.  Permanent tokens is the easier way to access the data.  The instructions on how to generate the permanent token is found in the GIF animation here:

https://www.deputy.com/api-doc/API/Authentication/
This is the code I use in Excel VBA to read the data

```
Sub Get_Data()
    Dim request As New WinHttpRequest
    Dim url As String, parameters As String
    Dim permanentAccessToken As String
    
    'Demo credentials
    permanentAccessToken = "892******************b3e05f0df0"
    url = "https://business.na.deputy.com/"
    url = url & "api/v1/resource/TimesheetPayReturn"
    request.Open "GET", url
    request.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "OAuth " + permanentAccessToken
    request.Send
    ' Check the result is valid
    If request.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Error: " & request.ResponseText
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

The permanent token is added to the header and that should work.